# Programmatically button in custom annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am making a annotationview, that includes a customized button. When this button is tapped, it should do something. First I will try to make it print. As it works now, the annotationview is closing, without printing anything. Its closing because I make a button.removeFromSuperview. 
Here's how it looks very shortly, and only focus on the button

```
class CustomAnnotation:  MKPinAnnotationView, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let infoButton : UIButton = UIButton.init(frame:CGRect(x: 250, y: -300, width: 40, height: 40))

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    super.setSelected(true, animated: animated)

    if(selected) {

    infoButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"home.png"), for: .normal)
    infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sayHello), for:.touchUpInside)

self.addSubview(infoButton)

} else {

infoButton.removeFromSuperview()

}

func sayHello(sender: UIButton!) {
print("I should print something...")
  }
}
```

All in the customized annotationview looks great. 
Im calling the CustomAnnotation class into my Viewcontroller in the viewForAnnotation function.

Answer (score 0):

It's executing the .removeFromSuperview() because you are setting selected to false, so your if statement always fails, and goes to the else.

Your line: 
    super.setSelected(false, animated: animated)

should be:
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

Comment: Sorry, didn't change anything

Comment: Set some breakpoints and figure out what's happening to selected and why your if statement is failing.

Comment: Its not the if statement thats failing. In the project, I've customized some labels too inside the if statement, and it works fine. But the button won't react

Comment: I'm going off the code you posted, your setting the target in the if statement and your remove from super view is in the else. You said the remove from superview is executing, which means your target isn't getting set in the if statement. But ok. Good luck.